# iPhone application crashes on start up in AppDelegate with SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

My application was launching literally 20 minutes ago, but now I can't even get it to load the login screen without crashing. It is crashing on 
AppDelegate, and the only error in the console is

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

using the bt command in the console gives the following stack trace

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x000000010bcea2c6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010bd3dbf1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 284
    frame #2: 0x000000010ba76a3c libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 120
    frame #3: 0x000000010acc37f8 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 231
    frame #4: 0x000000010acc39c7 libc++abi.dylib`demangling_terminate_handler() + 262
    frame #5: 0x0000000109e0dd7c libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 96
    frame #6: 0x000000010acd0e97 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x000000010acd0ae9 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x0000000109e0dcb4 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 37
    frame #9: 0x0000000109ef1eea CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 570
    frame #10: 0x000000010e7e2bb0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
    frame #11: 0x0000000117007dd0 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1621
  * frame #12: 0x0000000103f9812b TheBiggestBlunt`main at AppDelegate.swift:14:7
    frame #13: 0x000000010b94fd29 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

When I place a breakpoint in the AppDelegate class, which looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    //var actIdc = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
    //lazy var rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
    //var container = UIView(frame:rect)

    //var container: UIView = UIView()

    class func instance() -> AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

//    func showActivityIndicator(){
//        if let window = window{
//            let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
//            container = UIView(frame: rect)
//            //container = UIView()
//            container.frame = window.frame
//            container.center = window.center
//            container.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.8)
//            actIdc.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:40, height:40)
//            actIdc.center = CGPoint(x:container.frame.size.width/2,y:container.frame.size.height/2)
//            container.addSubview(actIdc)
//            window.addSubview(container)
//            actIdc.startAnimating()
//        }
//    }

//    func dismissActivityIndicator(){
//        if let _ = window{
//            container.removeFromSuperview()
//        }
//    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

It goes to the first uncommented line, then goes to the assembly code and then runs. You see the login page for 1 second, then the app gives a SIGABRT.

I have checked all IBOutlets, and nothing is wrong.

Anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file that needs to be added to your project

[image]